# C random chars inside char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc

I am making a c program that loads a small text file.  I store the read contents of the text file in a **char array**.  Here is the function that loads the file.

```
void load_text_file(char* filename) {
    FILE *fp;
    char *buf = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
    if (!buf) return NULL;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    fgets(buf, 255, (FILE*)fp);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<255;i++) {
        printf("%d - %c\n", i, buf[i]);
    }
}
```

When the for loop prints the output, this happens.  *(This is a shortened version of the output, I didn't want to put all 255 characters in this question.)*

```
0 - H
1 - e
2 - l
3 - l
4 - o
5 -  
6 - W
7 - o
8 - r
9 - l
10 - d
11 - !
//Random chars past this point
12 -  
13 - 
14 - „
15 - 
16 - „ 
//etc... etc... etc...
96 - Å
97 -  
98 -  
99 - Å
100 - å
101 - è
102 -
//etc... etc... etc...  
//all the way up to 255 chars
```

I am unsure what is causing this.

I want to know what is causing this and how I can fix it.

Comment: Let's say the file you're reading is only 12 bytes long. What do you expect the array to hold in the areas beyond byte #12? Why?

Comment: Your function leaks memory. And why do you `return NULL;` in a `void` function? Just declare your buffer as a static variable: `static char buf[255];`, and use `sizeof(buf)` instead of hardcoding 255 all over the place. You won't have to deal with dynamic allocation, which is utterly unnecessary as long as you intend to keep your buffer length constant.

Comment: OT: `load_text_file()` misses to `fclose()` `fp`.

Comment: Add a `memset(buf, '9', 255)` right before the call to `fgets()` and get enlightened ...

Comment: Also please not that `fgets()` reads as much as told **and** not more then until the next new-line. This  is clearly stated in its documentation ... (hint, hint... ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observe is not surprising, let's examine your code:

```
fgets(buf, 255, (FILE*)fp);
```

First there is no reason to cast `fp` to `(FILE*)`.  `fp` is defined with the correct type and casting pointers is a bad habit that will often lead to unreadable and buggy code.

`fgets(buf, 255, fp)` attempts to read upto 254 characters from the stream, stopping at the first `'\n'`. It returns a pointer to `buf`, unless no characters could be read, in which case the contents of the buffer are indeterminate and `NULL` is returned.

You should test this return value to verify that characters indeed were read from the stream, otherwise the content of the buffer could be random characters, probably what happened to already be in the heap space where `malloc()` found available memory.

When `fgets()` encounters a line feed or if 254 characters have been stored to the buffer, it stores a `'\0'` byte after the characters read and returns a pointer to the buffer.  The contents of the buffer beyond this NUL byte are indeterminate, as above, they could be NUL or apparently random characters, or anything at all...

You should rewrite your loop this way to only dump meaningful characters:

```
void load_text_file(const char *filename) {
    char *buf = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
    if (!buf) { printf("could not allocate memory\n"); return; }

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp) { printf("could not open file\n"); return; }

    if (fgets(buf, 255, (FILE*)fp)) {
        for (int i = 0; buf[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            printf("%d - %c\n", i, buf[i]);
        }
        ...  // do something else with `buf`
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(buf);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should print your `buf` as:

```
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

The garbage you see is uninitialized RAM memory allocated for your `buf` with `malloc` and not touched by `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` reads either till the end of your stream(first 254 characters in this case) or till the first `'\0'` is encountered. If you are reading past any `'\0'`, you will get garbage values as output. So, instead of executing the loop till 255, you should execute it only till the first `'\0'` is found.